# Equality Comparison of two Objects in C#

Tags: c#, equality

This is a Fundamental type question, forgive me for being so amateurish.

Case 1:

```
Employee _emp1 = new Employee();
Employee _emp2 = _emp1;
_emp1.Equals(_emp2) ==> RETURNS a True !!
```

Case2:

```
Employee _emp1 = new Employee();
Employee _emp2 = new Employee();
_emp1.Equals(_emp2) ==> RETURNS a False !!
```

Could you explain me the above Comparison method and reason interms of Memory-Mapping and allocation perspective ?

Comment: Case 1 surprises you? C++ background?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess so,Bingo!!

Comment: -1 sorry but I don't think SO is the place for this level of question. This sort of thing has been covered ad nauseum in MSDN and blogs.

Comment: what does this have to do with oop? Suggest you retag this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Employee _emp1 = new Employee();
```

Everytime you have `new Employee()` you have new memory allocated in heap and stack.

means _emp1 is value in memory pointing to heap say 1212.

Now you have second statement

```
Employee _emp2 = new Employee();
```

So again new value _emp2 say 1414 in heap.

That's why _emp1.Equals(_emp2) returns false here.

when you say

```
_emp1 = _emp2
```

You are assigning the same values in both.

Answer (score 9):

Simply speaking, the default comparator compares object instances.

- In your first example, both `_emp1` and `_emp2` are pointing to the same instance of `Employee` and therefore `Equals` returns true.
- In your second example, you create two `Employee` objects, `_emp1` and `_emp2` being two distinctly different objects. Therefore, `Equals` returns false.

---

Note that copy constructors are *not implicitly called* for reference types. Were you to do:

```
Employee _emp1 = new Employee();
Employee _emp2 = new Employee(_emp1); //or _emp1.Clone() if that is implemented
```

then `Equals` using a the default comparator will return false since they are two unique objects.

Also note that this behavior is *not the same* for value types.

---

Furthermore, if you (as you should) override the default behavior of `Equals` and `CompareTo`, all the above becomes moot. A standard technique might be (assuming a little bit):

```
public bool Equals(object rhs)
{
    var rhsEmployee = rhs as Employee;
    if(rhsEmployee == null) return false;

    return this.Equals(rhsEmployee);
}

public bool Equals(Employee rhs)
{
     return this.EmployeeId == rhs.EmployeeId;
}
```

---

Further reading:

- [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)
- [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)
- [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: In your first Bullet you mean to say: _emp1 and _emp2 both point to the same Memory Location. and in Second _emp1 and _emp2 point to two different memory location. Well has this anything to do with Stacks, Heap??

Comment: @LetsKickSomeAssin.net Semantically it is the same thing, yes. However, in the Managed world, we tend to avoid talking directly about memory as we usually do not have direct control over it. But yes, under the hood it is checking [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) which compares the two pointer values.

Comment: This won't compile, as the compiler refuses to convert `null` to `bool`. If the other instance is no `Employee`, `Equals` should return `false`.

Comment: @Nuffin Thanks. I meant `false`.

Comment: @Nuffin Thank you again for the edit. I think I was tired... :(

Answer (score 2):

"This apple belongs to Joe. This pear belongs to the same man. Is this apple's owner the same person as this pear's owner? Yes."

"This apple belongs to Susan. This pear belongs to Susan. Is this apple's owner the same person as this pear's owner? No, they just happen to both be called Susan."

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own `Equals` method. By default `Equals` is called from `Object` class, which is basically check if these two references points to one object (i.e. `Object.ReferenceEqual(object, object)` is called)

Answer (score 1):

`Employee`, does not implement it's own `.Equals()` method, then it is using `Object.Equals()`, which is only comparing the references. In case 1, your two references are made equal when assigning.

If you want to compare the `Employee` objects by their internal properties, you should implement your own `.Equals()` method that returns true if all those properties values match, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of equating the two seperate instances of employee, you need a way of equating whether they are equal because they are seperate instances. In case one, the instances are the same and `_emp2` is `_emp1` You can do this by implementing the `IEquatable<T>` interface.

```
public class Employee : IEquatable<Employee>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public bool Equals(Employee other)
  {
    return other.Id == Id;
  } 
}
```

You can then do this

```
Employee e = new Employee() { Id = 1 };
Employee e2 = new Employee() { Id = 1 };
//Returns true
bool b = e.Equals(e2);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `Employee _emp1` you are allocating the memory which is needed to store a pointer to another piece of memory that will contain an instance of Employee.

`new Employee();` allocates a new piece of memory filling it with an instance of Employee and return you the address of this memory (the pointer). Something like, let's say, 1234567. So after Executing `Employee _emp1 = new Employee();`, you have `_emp1` equal to 1234567, and the memory pointed by 1234567 containing your Employee.

Then you execute `Employee _emp2 = _emp1;`, and the result is having another piece of memory able to contain an address to a piece of memory containing an instance of Employee (`_emp2`) which is equal to 1234567, too. This meand that when you execute `_emp1.Equals(_emp2)` the result is true, since both of your vars point to the same piece of memory.

In the second case, another instance of Employee is created and put in a different piece of memory (e.g. something like 7654321) and this address is assigned to `_emp2` that hence is different from `_emp1`.